# Which one is correct: "As far as we are concerned too" or "as far as we are concerned as well"?

Tags: usage

What I'm trying to express is "as far as we're concerned___________, that is indeed his biggest work".

How do I phrase it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Taking your example

> as far as we're concerned___________, that is indeed his biggest work

both of your suggestions

> as far as we're concerned too, that is indeed his biggest work".
> as far as we're concerned as well, that is indeed his biggest work".

would work but I would prefer

> as far as we too are concerned, that is indeed his biggest work".